# how to convert the text outputted from a database to links?

Tags: php, mysql

Iam class 11th..recently I started learning php and mysqliI have been facing a problem. I am trying to create a database which has a small list of movies.when the page loads, it displays the list of those movies from database..but the problem is, it displays them as a simple text..i Want them to be like links so that whenever it is clicked it displays the info about that particular movie..but i dont want to write anchor tag links for each movie..Is there any other way?

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM movies";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: To some people it might no be "obvious". No need to be rude and call people lazy just because they don't know something.

Comment: @taxicala ... it's a homework question, by answering it you're doing his homework for him ... ergo John Conde's *1. Don't be lazy* I'd guess

Comment: @CD001 It's still no valid reason to be disrespectful.

Comment: Thanks a lot people..thats exactly what i was hoping for..I really learned something new here.. @CD001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  $htmlLink = '';

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $htmlLink .= "<a href='movie.php?{$id}'>id: {$id} - Name: {$title}</a><br>";

    echo $htmlLink;

  }

} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

**Then on your movie.php page use $_GET[] to get the query string data**

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"].  "<br>";
```

With:

```
$id = $row["id"];
$title = $row["title"];
echo "<a href='/movie/{$id}'>id: {$id} - Name: {$title}</a><br>";
```

Comment: sorry of asking this but can u explain me what you have done..Iam little confused here..especially the echo part@taxicala

Comment: i'm just echoing a link as you've requested. The href is something you should change in order to match your routes but it's just a concept.

Comment: okay..Thankyou very much..It ll really help me learning @taxicala